How can I get variation in a carpet texture
I'm using this image as reference for what I want my carpet to look like:

The carpet has a lot of variation as most carpet does especially in the bottom left corner. I want to know how to turn a normal carpet material into one that has the detail of the one in the image but all the textures I found online don't have anything like it so I would assume its procedural or a particle system.

Perhaps a useful video: Youtube: Blender Guru: How to Tile a Texture Without Repetition - Blender Tutorial

A noise texture with a very small scale value being used to run a brightness value might do what you want.

Yes, add noise, please share just one of your objects, like the floor, so that we can tweak the material

i found a material that suited my needs and should look similar to the picture with some added noise
https://3dtextures.me/2020/03/25/fabric-rug-006/
